# iOS 8 breaks separator lines in UITableViews

Tags: ios8, xcode6, separator

[image]

I've tried a variety of the `layoutMargins` code bits and it still doesn't seem to have any effect to fix this weirdness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My subclassed `UITableViewCell` was missing `[super layoutSubviews]`.   (oops)

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];  // <-- important!
...
```

Comment: Easy mistake to make and this definitely saved me hours of debugging. Thank you for posting this answer.